# "I got in touch with Sara"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

Does "I got in touch with Sara" mean "I contacted Sara/I reached out to Sara" or "I have been in touch with Sara"/as in before"

Comment: "got ____" usually refers to a *change* in status, so it wouldn't make sense to use it to being in touch with Sara continuously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I got in touch with Sarah" = You contacted her once.

"I have been in touch with Sarah" = You have been in contact with her over a period of time and you have contacted each other a number of times during that period.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any difference in meaning between "I contacted Sara" and "I have been in touch with Sara".

Both refer to past events.

But "I got in touch with Sara" is past tense, so formally it is closer to "I contacted Sara".

Comment: Do you not think "in touch" in " i have been in touch with Sara" is an adjective?

Comment: no, it is a prepositional phrase.  "in" is a preposition and "touch" is a noun,